# NPM install and upgrade throws Couldn't find package error when used in monorepo

Tags: npm, npm-install

Recently my shared monorepo package is not being resolved properly is is being treated as npm package not a monorepo package causing an error.

```html
$ yarn install
yarn install v1.19.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Couldn't find package "@placeholderName/common@^1.0.307" required by "@placeholderName/browser@1.0.307" on the "npm" registry.   
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Error: Couldn't find package "@placeholderName/common@^1.0.307" required by "@placeholderName/server@1.0.307" on the "npm" registry.   
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:750:123)
    at PackageRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:36539:17)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:304:30)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:317:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Im unsure of how to get rid of this annoying error and I've been trying for a while